# Can Airnotifier be installed alongside Moodle on the same LAMP server?

Tags: server, moodle

I am not sure if Airnotifier needs a dedicated server or can it be installed alongside an existing Moodle installation on the same server?

I have not tried installing the Airnotifier till now as I am afraid it may hamper my existing installation on Moodle.